# Update custom product attribute programatically?

Tags: magento2, attributes

How can I update custom attribute of a product programatically?

**$product->setCustomAttrName('value')** does not work

Comment: When we create custom attribute we need to set and save both like $product->setCustomAttribute('value') and $product->save(); this works.

Comment: Reply with this and Ill mark it as the answer if u want. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by first setting the value of custom attribute and then save product.

```
$product->setCustomAttribute('value') 
$product->save();
```